# How to get the Element Id of Control in UserControl using JavaScript in Ext.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ext.net

Hai,

I am Writing Age calculation based on DateField value using JavaScript function and trying to fill the value in another Numeric textBox. using the following code.

```
<script>

        function getAge(event, toolEl, panel, tc) {
            debugger;
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(event.getValue());
            var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                age--;
            }
            if (event.name == 'dtMotherDOB') {
                Ext.getCmp('txtMotherAge').setValue(age);
            }
            else
                Ext.getCmp('txtFatherAge').setValue(age);
            return age;
        }


    </script>


 <ext:DateField ID="dtFatherDOB" runat="server"  FieldLabel="Father DOB"  
                                        Vtype="daterange" EndDateField="dtDOB" EnableKeyEvents="true">
         <Listeners>
                 <Select Fn="getAge"/>
        </Listeners>
  </ext:DateField>

  <ext:NumberField ID="txtFatherAge" runat="server" FieldLabel="Father Age"                       Width="300"  MinValue="20">

    </ext:NumberField>
```

In above code after selecting the `DataField` value the i am filling the `txtMotherAge` value in `textBox`.

using the above code.    `Ext.getCmp('txtFatherAge').setValue(age);` is used to get the element from form and setting the value of age in `textbox`.

The above code is working fine for the simple form.

but when i use this code in UserControl and consume the usercontrol in anotherform.  `Ext.getCmp('txtFatherAge').setValue(age)` showing error and `Ext.getCmp('txtFatherAge')` value becomes `'undefined'`.

what is the problem in the above code. how to get the element in usercontrol in ext.net control.

Please help me in this regard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ext.getCmp('<%=UserControl1.ClientID%>' + '_' + 'txtFatherAge').setValue(age)
```

Or,

Set `ClientIDMode="Static"`

```
<ext:NumberField ID="txtFatherAge" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"    
 FieldLabel="Father Age" Width="300"  MinValue="20"></ext:NumberField>
```

Comment: Hai,i changed the endDateField value in config item as like below '<ext:DateField ID="dtDOB" Vtype="daterange" MaxLength="10" EnableKeyEvents="true"   MaxDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>" ClientIDMode="Static">
 <CustomConfig> <ext:ConfigItem Name="endDateField" Value="'<%=this.ClientID%>' + '_' + 'dtDoJ'" Mode="Value" />  <ext:ConfigItem Name="startDateField" Value="'<%=this.ClientID%>' + '_' + 'dtFatherDOB'" Mode="Value" /> </CustomConfig>'  But it showing error like ** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setMaxValue' of undefined **  This code is also in UserControl. Please help me in this. TQ